# SQL WHERE not working with Discord

Tags: java, discord

So I am getting a database and my discord bot is connecting to the database but when I get it I am getting an error of com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'd1aa852e1a504d6cafbd55e0d2d28dea' in 'where clause'
Here is my code

```
int id = SQLUser.getIntFromDatabase("SELECT * FROM Players WHERE UUID = " + uuid.toString() + "", "ID");
if(id==-1) channel.sendMessage("ID is not valid please login to the WidowMC").queue();
else 
{
    Message messa = new MessageBuilder().append(Utils.getName(uuid) + " Skull").build();
    channel.sendFile(Utils.getSkullFile(Utils.getName(uuid)), messa).queue();
    channel.sendMessage("ID = " + id);
}

public static void excuteQuery(String query) 
{
    Connection conn = Core.getConnection();
    try
    {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around the uuid to make it a literal, otherwise Mysql thinks you're referring to a column.

Also be very careful, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, use the [Prepared Stamements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) correctly could help you removing the vulnerability.

Comment: Like 'uuid'? Or is it something else?

Comment: You're looking for an exact match so you can use '='. The problem comes from a wrong syntax (missing quotes). Take a look at the examples in the docs page I've linked. [Anchor to parameters section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps)